# How to trigger same animation without stopping the previous ones

Tags: javascript, html, css, random

I have the codes below of a bullet animation, basically just a straight movement from left to right but with a random Y position.

My issue is that I'd like to make it so that when it triggers again for the second time, it won't stop the previous animation. That means the next animation will overlay the previous ones if the previous animation hasn't finished.

```js
(function randomBullet() {
  const bulletPosY = [
    "posY1",
    "posY2",
    "posY3",
    "posY4",
    "posY5"
  ];

  const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * bulletPosY.length);
  document.querySelector(".randomBulletPos").classList.add(bulletPosY[random]);
}());
```

```css
.bullet {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  animation: bullet linear 5s;
  filter: hue-rotate(186deg);
}

@keyframes bullet {
  0% {
    left: 0%;
    opacity: 0%;
  }
  5% {
    left: 5%;
    opacity: 100%;
  }
  20% {
    left: 15%;
    opacity: 100%;
  }
  70% {
    opacity: 0%;
  }
  100% {
    left: 70%;
    opacity: 0%;
  }
}

.posY1 {
  --top: 50%;
}

.posY2 {
  --top: 40%;
}

.posY3 {
  --top: 30%;
}

.posY4 {
  --top: 20%;
}

.posY5 {
  --top: 10%;
}

.randomBulletPos {
  bottom: var(--top);
}
```

```html
<img class="bullet randomBulletPos" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/qgNyF.png?s=328&g=1" />
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: An animation won't duplicate an element... You need to manage the elements yourself in that case.

Comment: What do you mean by *"next animation will overlay the previous ones"*? Please be more specific. Also, you should not create animations using the `left` property. Rather the GPU accelerable `transform` `translate` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your task it to **create** many *bullets* simultaneously at random Y positions, I suggest you create your elements from in-memory.

- Create some DOM utility functions for querying elements and new elements creation
- Create a `rand` helper function that accepts a `m` *min* and `M` *max* range
- Create a `setTimeout` that will recall your function in a loop fashion. Also set to a *rand(min, max)* timeout value
- Use [Element.append()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/append) to insert your created (img) elements.
- Don't forget to [remove()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/remove) your element from the DOM on ["animationend" Event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/animationend_event)

```js
// DOM helpers:
const el = (sel, par) => (par || document).querySelector(sel);
const elNew = (tag, prop) => Object.assign(document.createElement(tag), prop);

// Utility functions:
const rand = (m, M) => ~~(Math.random() * (M - m) + m);

// Task: Bullets:
const randomBullet = () => {

  // Create a new bullet:
  const elBullet = elNew("img", {
    className: `bullet posY${rand(1, 6)}`,
    src: "https://i.stack.imgur.com/qgNyF.png?s=328&g=1",
    style: `filter: hue-rotate(${rand(0, 360)}deg)`
  });
  
  // Remove from DOM once its animation finishes:
  elBullet.addEventListener("animationend", () => {
    elBullet.remove();
  });
  
  // Insert it where desired:
  el("body").append(elBullet);
  
  // Schedule a new bullet creation:
  setTimeout(() => randomBullet(), rand(500, 2000));
};

randomBullet();
```

```css
.bullet {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  animation: bullet linear 5s forwards;
  top: var(--top);
}

@keyframes bullet {
  0%   { opacity: 0; translate: 0% 0; }
  5%   { opacity: 1; translate: 5vw 0; }
  20%  { opacity: 1; translate: 15vw 0; }
  70%  { opacity: 0; }
  100% { opacity: 0; translate: 70vw 0;  }
}

.posY1 { --top: 50%; }
.posY2 { --top: 40%; }
.posY3 { --top: 30%; }
.posY4 { --top: 20%; }
.posY5 { --top: 10%; }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. This has helped me achieve my aim :D

Comment: Hi, I was just thinking to add another image and also text, in the same line. I've been trying to tweak the code such as adding another 'src', and more but all my attempts failed. 

So current code, the animation is: image
I'd like it to be: image + image2 + text

Do you think you could also help with this one? >.<

Comment: @rich I'm not sure what is that you want to build from that description, sorry.

Comment: Ok another example, from the code above inside 'const elBullet' currently has 1 image only, hence, only 1 image will fly at a time. I would like it to be 2 images and a text that flies at a time, all in one line in this order: image1, image2, text. So visually we can see it flies starting with text in front, image2 behind text, and image1 behind image2. Hope you can understand better now. Otherwise it's totally fine, you helped enough .

Comment: @rich You mean something like: https://jsfiddle.net/yw5st9zh/1/ ?

Comment: Ok, almost there. Right now it comes out randomly, I'd like it to come out together in one line like this: shorturl.at/gimV4

Comment: @rich simply use `innerHTML` than: https://jsfiddle.net/bhaj0cxf/2/ - and change a bit the CSS as well... You can do it.